# Property 'text' does not exist on type 'File'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, webpack-encore, typescript-eslint

I have the following code to handle a user's file upload:

```
17  const onFileDrop =
18    (files: File[]) => {
19      files.forEach(file => file.text().then(content => console.log(content)));
20    },
21  );
```

VS Code is not showing any errors and I can properly access the `File` interface, which contains a `text()` function.

[image]
[image]

However, when running `npm start` I see the following errors:

```
[tsl] ERROR in {omitted}/RawCommandOutputs.tsx(19,34)
      TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'File'.


[tsl] ERROR in {omitted}/RawCommandOutputs.tsx(19,46)
      TS7006: Parameter 'content' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in behaviour was due to different versions of Typescript being used by webpack and VS Code.

The project had a dependency on on Typescript version 3.5.2. In this version, the `File` interface doesn't contain a `text()` function. Hence, running `npm start` was showing the aforementioned errors.

VS Code appears to use the latest version of Typescript by default (3.9.5 in my case), which contains the updated `File` interface.

To make VS Code use the same version of Typescript as my project, I added
`"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"` to my `settings.json` file. Then, I ran the `Select Typescript Version` command and chose the `Use Workspace Version` option.

Comment: Amazing!
I faced the same issue with a project we have that uses a different version of TS than the one VS Code was employing and I was getting compilation errors with npm start but VS Code was happy LOL! (and the project did seem to run fine)