# TypeError, text is not a function when attempting to use text() from either Blob or File

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, docker-compose

I'm trying to figure out why my node.js express backend using TypeScript is not recognizing the functions that are defined in the typescript lib.dom.d.ts file. The interfaces/types in question are File/Blob, a File extends a Blob and the function I'm trying to access is text() from the Blob interface, exert below from lib.dom.d.ts file from typescript v3.9.5

```
interface Blob {
    readonly size: number;
    readonly type: string;
    arrayBuffer(): Promise<ArrayBuffer>;
    slice(start?: number, end?: number, contentType?: string): Blob;
    stream(): ReadableStream;
    text(): Promise<string>;
}
```

I'm generating a PDF from a div on the frontend and then sending the pdf as a File type to the backend.

In VSCode I am able to cast my File as either a File or Blob to see the IntelliSense auto-complete option for all the readonly and functions listed above from the Blob interface.

Despite this, my API is failing as soon as I try to use the .text() function, stating that ${variableName}.text is not a function.

I have tried to update my TypeScript to v3.9.5 per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62440273/property-text-does-not-exist-on-type-file)
and have set my TypeScript version to my Workspace Version.

I have confirmed that the incoming data is coming in as a File type by console.logging the variable before attempting to use the text() function. I have also tried to cast the variable as a File and a Blob using IntelliSense to complete the call.

I have tried to wipe my docker container that's running my nodeJS express backend.

Comment: Does the error happen in runtime?

Comment: @Konrad  yes, no startup errors; just errors out when trying to use text()

Comment: It means that it's unrelated to typescript. Your variable isn't a blob hence no `text` method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Konrad, I determine that the issue was that NodeJS does not have a Blob or File type by outputting `${variable} instanceof File/Blob` and each type was giving me a File/Blob is not defined error.
Looks like VSCode/Typescript were incorrectly suggesting that they did exists.

This is the solution I came up with

```
function filePathToBase64(file: string): string {
  let bitmap: Buffer = fs.readFileSync(file);
  return buffer.from(bitmap).toString('base64');
}
```

I used NodeJS's fs and just read the incoming FormData's File's path which was like `/tmp/${random generated path}`

Cheers.